# C# assigning Func to an event

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a filehelper utility and I am getting issue in assigning Func to an event. It says non assignable.

The event and delegate signature is as below

```
public event AfterReadHandler<T> AfterReadRecord
public delegate void AfterReadHandler<T>(EngineBase engine, fterReadEventArgs<T> e);
```

The code is as below

```
public class FileHelperUtility<T> where T : class
    {

        public List<T> ParseFile<T>(string fileName, ImportFileError fileError,Func<EngineBase, AfterReadEventArgs<T> > afterReadFunc ) where T : class
        {
            List<T> records = new List<T>();
            var fileEngine = InitializeFileEngine<T>(afterReadFunc);
            records = fileEngine.ReadFile(fileName).ToList();
            if (ValidateHeader(fileEngine.HeaderText))
            {
                fileError.ErrorType = ImportFileFaultType.InvalidHeaderRecordType;
                fileError.ErrorMessage = "No header record in the file.";
            }
            else
            {
                PopulateErrors(fileError, fileEngine.ErrorManager);
            }
            return records;
        }

        private FileHelperEngine<T> InitializeFileEngine<T>(Func<EngineBase, AfterReadEventArgs<T>> afterReadFunc) where T : class
        {
            var fileEngine = new FileHelperEngine<T>(Encoding.Default);
            fileEngine.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;
            if (afterReadFunc != null)
            {
                fileEngine.AfterReadRecord += afterReadFunc;
            }
            return fileEngine;
        }


        private void PopulateErrors(ImportFileError fileError, ErrorManager errorManager)
        {
            if (errorManager.Errors.Count() > 0)
            {
                fileError.ErrorType = ImportFileFaultType.InvalidDetailRecordType;
                fileError.ErrorData = new List<string>();
            }
            foreach (var error in errorManager.Errors)
            {
                string errorString = string.Format("Line:{0} Field:{1} - ErrorInfo:{2}",
                    error.LineNumber,
                    ((ConvertException)error.ExceptionInfo).FieldName,
                    error.ExceptionInfo.InnerException);
                fileError.ErrorData.Add(errorString);
            }

        }
        private bool ValidateHeader(string headerRecord)
        {
            bool isheaderValid;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerRecord) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerRecord.Trim(new char[] { '\r', '\n' })))
            {
                isheaderValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isheaderValid = false;
            }
            return isheaderValid;
        }



    }
```

I am getting the non- assignable error at  `fileEngine.AfterReadRecord += afterReadFunc;`

Can Someone help.

Comment: You want an `Action<...>` instead of `Func<...>`.

Comment: Your question contains code that is very difficult to get to compile. You really need to provide a [mcve] for us to work from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've cut your code down slightly, but the issue is that an `AfterReadHandler<T>` isn't an `Func<EngineBase, AfterReadEventArgs<T>>` (nor is it a `Action<EngineBase, AfterReadEventArgs<T>>`.

You have two choices to fix your code.

(1)

```
private FileHelperUtility<T> InitializeFileEngine<T>(AfterReadHandler<T> afterReadFunc) where T : class
{
    var fileEngine = new FileHelperUtility<T>();
    if (afterReadFunc != null)
    {
        fileEngine.AfterReadRecord += afterReadFunc;
    }
    return fileEngine;
}
```

(2)

```
private FileHelperUtility<T> InitializeFileEngine<T>(Action<EngineBase, AfterReadEventArgs<T>> afterReadFunc) where T : class
{
    var fileEngine = new FileHelperUtility<T>();
    if (afterReadFunc != null)
    {
        fileEngine.AfterReadRecord += (eb, area) => afterReadFunc(eb, area);
    }
    return fileEngine;
}
```

Let me know if this isn't clear enough.

Comment: This is helpful. I will make minimal complete example hence. Thanks,.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand that you're using `Func<T, TResult>` Delegate the second param is TResult it's not the same with AfterReadHandler delegate.

Can you try to use `Action<T1, T2>` Delegate instead.

Refs here:
[Func in msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx),
[Action in msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549311(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: When I change Func to Action, it shows this error    Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Action<FileHelpers.EngineBase,FileHelpers.Events.AfterReadEventArgs<T>>' to 'FileHelpers.Events.AfterReadHandler<T>'

Comment: Thanks for your direction.